# Angular controller scope/variables not appearing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ng-controller

I'm trying to clean up my code such that it corresponds to John Papa's Angular style guide but in the process broke something and my controller no longer appears in ng-inspector.  If I can get vm.message to display I can figure out the rest (though any general feedback is appreciated :))

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";

  angular
    .module('roomchoice.manager-dashboard.alerts', [
      'ui.router'
    ])

    .config(function config($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider.state('manager.alerts', {
        url: '/alerts',
        views: {
          "main": {
            controller: 'AlertsController',
            templateUrl: 'manager-dashboard/alerts/alerts.tpl.html'
          }
        },
        data: {
          pageTitle: 'Alerts'
        }
      });
    })

    .controller('AlertsController', AlertsController);

    function AlertsController($scope, Restangular) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.message = "Hello";
      vm.settlements = [];
      vm.undepositedPayments = [];
      vm.unapprovedFunnels = [];
      vm.getSettlements = getSettlements;
      vm.getUndepositedPayments = get_UndepositedPayments;
      vm.getUnapprovedFunnels = get_unapprovedFunnels;

      function getSettlements() {
        Restangular.all('alerts/get_settlements').getList().then(function(settlements){
          vm.settlements = settlements;
          return vm.settlements;
        });
      }//End of getSettlements

      function getUndepositedPayments() {
        Restangular.all('alerts/get_undepositedpayments').getList().then(function(undepositedpayments){
          vm.undepositedPayments = undepositedpayments;
          return vm.undepositedPayments;
        });
      }//End of getUndepositedPayments

      function getUnapprovedFunnels() {
        Restangular.all('alerts/get_unapprovedfunnels').getList().then(function(unapprovedfunnels){
          vm.unapprovedFunnels = unapprovedfunnels;
          return vm.unapprovedFunnels;
        });
      }//End of getUnapprovedFunnels
    }//End of Controller
})();//End of Module
```

```html
<div id="main" ng-controller="AlertsController as alerts">
 <div>
  <h1>Alerts (Under Construction) </h1>
  <h2>{{alerts.message}}</h2>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any error in the console? the one on here says angular not defined but i take for granted you have it in your working copy.

Comment: Are you getting any error? the `Alerts (Under Construction)` text is shown?

Comment: don't use `controller` on your state and `ng-controller` in your template at the same time.  remove the `ng-controller` in the template, and add `controllerAs: alerts` in your state definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate your controller more than once in your code, and this won't work the way you expect.

You should not use `ng-controller` in templates that are part of a state.  The controller is defined by the state provider, and does not be instantiated inside the template.

Remove `ng-controller` from your template, and add `controllerAs` to your state:

```
$stateProvider.state('manager.alerts', {
    url: '/alerts',
    views: {
      "main": {
        controller: 'AlertsController',
        controllerAs: 'alerts',
        templateUrl: 'manager-dashboard/alerts/alerts.tpl.html'
      }
    },
    data: {
      pageTitle: 'Alerts'
    }
  });
```